# How to obtain first day of next month in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a date of operation. I want create promissory notes which have got:

```
day=1
month= the next month of operation_date
year= automatic
```

Example :

```
operation_date = 15/11/2010 
promissory_note1_date = 1/12/2010
promissory_note2_date = 1/01/2011
promissory_note3_date = 1/02/2011
promissory_note4_date = 1/02/2011
```

if exist four promissory notes

How could I make it?

PD: Excuse me my syntax

Answer (score 205, accepted):

You can do

```
require "active_support"

require "active_support/core_ext/date/calculations"
# || require "active_support/all"

Date.today.at_beginning_of_month
#=> Wed, 01 Dec 2010

Date.today.at_beginning_of_month.next_month
#=> Sat, 01 Jan 2011

Date.today.at_beginning_of_month.next_month.next_month
#=> Tue, 01 Feb 2011
```

And so on...

##### References

[Rails guide 3.0 - 6.1.4 - ActiveSupport - How to Load Core Extensions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#how-to-load-core-extensions)
[Rails guide 3.0 - 6.1.4 - ActiveSupport - Extensions to date](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-date)

Comment: `at_beginning_of_month` and so on are provided by ActiveSupport, and are thus available in Rails, but not in pure Ruby.

Comment: Just for clarification: this is not pure Ruby but part of the Rails extensions, you need `require "active_support/core_ext"` to make this works

Comment: Btw, [`Date.today.beginning_of_month`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-beginning_of_month) works, too.

Answer (score 20):

In case you are not using `rails` or do not wish to require `active_support`, I found a simpler way without active_support

```
(Date.today - Date.today.mday + 1) # First day of the current month
=> Thu, 01 Dec 2016
```

Hope this helps! :-)

Comment: Nice, thanks. And without the +1 it's the last of the previous month, which is also nice :)

Answer (score 12):

A response to generically obtain N months (in rails)

```
(Date.today + N.months).at_beginning_of_month
```

Comment: A "generic" response which doesn't work in plain Ruby.

Answer (score 8):

My solution:

```
class Time
  def start_of_next_month
    Time.local(self.year + self.month / 12, self.month % 12 + 1)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7):

I am using Ruby `1.8.7` and `1.9.2` with `rvm` and in both cases `Date.today` results an error:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p302 > Date.today
NameError: uninitialized constant Date

ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Date.today
NameError: uninitialized constant Object::Date
```

I thing you should use `Time.now`
and this link should help you http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_ruby/datesandtimes.html .

I am not sure about availability of `at_beginning_of_month` method in ruby but it does exists in RoR.

Comment: I've done it in rails console. If you want to use it without rails, you need to require activesupport

Comment: ruby-1.8.7-p302 > require 'date' will solve the NameError problem and Date.today will work

Comment: As ravi says, `date` is not fully loaded by default.

Comment: Date.today >> n will increment the date by 'n' months.
And also Date.today.day and Date.today.month will give you the current date and month.

Comment: at_beginning_of_month will be available to you if you install active_support

Answer (score 5):

for those working with Time class :

```
class Time
        def start_of_next_month
                t = Time.local(self.year,self.month)+45*24*3600;
                Time.local(t.year,t.month)
        end
end
```

I know it's little clumsy :)

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to get the first monday of the year (for a rails fixture) and the following worked:

```
Date.new(Date.today.year,1,1).beginning_of_week
```

If you aren't in rails, it can be like below,

```
# get the last day of the previous year
d = Date.new(Date.today.year - 1,12,31)
# advance to the next monday. This relies on w.day being 0..6, where 0 is sunday.
first_monday = d + (8 - d.wday).days
```

Answer (score 2):

As Nov 2017, `at_beginning_of_month` is no more supported in the latest version. You can use `beginning_of_month` instead, considering you are using Rails

Comment: Thanks! And to save the googling for the next person. This is the apidock link for this method as of Rails 6.0.0 https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/DateAndTime/Calculations/beginning_of_month

Answer (score 1):

ActiveSupport seems a little heavyweight to load for this. I would do it this way:

```
require 'date'
first = Date.new(Date.today.year, Date.today.month, 1)
4.times do |m|
  puts "Promissory note due on #{first >> (m + 1)}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 (DateTime.now.beginning_of_year..DateTime.now.end_of_year).to_a.select {|k| k if k == k.beginning_of_month}
=> [Wed, 01 Jan 2020 00:00:00 +0530, Sat, 01 Feb 2020 00:00:00 +0530, Sun, 01 Mar 2020 00:00:00 +0530, Wed, 01 Apr 2020 00:00:00 +0530, Fri, 01 May 2020 00:00:00 +0530, Mon, 01 Jun 2020 00:00:00 +0530, Wed, 01 Jul 2020 00:00:00 +0530, Sat, 01 Aug 2020 00:00:00 +0530, Tue, 01 Sep 2020 00:00:00 +0530, Thu, 01 Oct 2020 00:00:00 +0530, Sun, 01 Nov 2020 00:00:00 +0530, Tue, 01 Dec 2020 00:00:00 +0530]
```

Answer (score 0):

This gem `extended_date` makes it easy, if you are trying it in Rails App.
This will help us to get first occurrence of any day in a month

`Date.today.first_day_of_month("friday")
 Date.today.first_day_of_month(5)
 Date.today.first_day_of_month(0)`